# i want to communicate from my gridcontrol to the the viewmodel of the view where it is hosted

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a scenario where in i want to communicate between my gridcontrol ( which is a custom control of the infragistics xam grid control) to the viewmodel of the view that hosts this gridcontrol.

I just got into WPF and would like to know the best ways of solving this issue.

The structure is as follows

View
(Control)
||
View Model(of the view)

Comment: Well first of all "View (Control) || View Model(of the view) " Explains it all , well put ! 

secondly look into something called DataBinding it's not that common in WPF so you might have a problem locating some good documentation on the matter

Comment: Wow Eran, I didn't think that sarcasm came across very well when writing, but you seem to have managed to do that admirably. I think what my friend Eran here was trying to say was something along the lines of 'if you do some basic research on WPF and/or MVVM, you'll be amazed at what you can find out... particularly on the data binding front'. If that wasn't what he was trying to say then I'll just say it instead.

Comment: I am aware of the data binding   thing , i was looking if i could fire an event or a command in the grid control which could be handled in the viewmodel of the view .

Comment: If you were truly aware of the data binding thing you would know it's exactly what you need to do what you ask.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is extremely vague, giving no indication as to what you are trying to bind too? I assume you are trying to bind to a property on the view model?

View - Its as simple as using DataBinding syntax.

```
<Grid ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}">
...
</Grid>
```

ViewModel: Expose a property which implements INotifyPropertyChanged

```
private List<Something> someCollection;

public List<Something> SomeCollection
{
get
{
    return this.someCollection;
}
set
{
    this.someCollection = value;
    this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.SomeCollection)
}
}
```

This is something you should be able to Google in seconds and find an answer, also I would expect that ANY WPF tutorial will start with an introduction to Data Binding.